# Interconvertible types and ambiguous calls

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a sequence of types, which I want to be freely convertible to one another. Consider the following toy example:

```
struct A {
  int value;
  A(int v) : value(v) { }
};

struct B {
  int value;
  B(int v) : value(v) { }
  B(A a) : value(a.value) { }
  operator A() const { return A(value); }
};

struct C {
  int value;
  C(int v) : value(v) { }
  C(A a) : value(a.value) { }
  C(B b) : value(b.value) { }
  operator B() const { return B(value); }
  operator A() const { return A(B(*this)); } // <-- ambiguous
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  C c(5);
  A a(3);
  a = c;
}
```

So as you see, I'm trying to defined each subsequent type to be convertible from all previous types using cast constructors, and to be convertible to all previous types using cast operators. Alas, this does not work as intended, as the definition of `C::operator A` is ambiguous according to gcc 4.7:

```
 In member function ‘C::operator A() const’:
19:40: error: call of overloaded ‘B(const C&)’ is ambiguous
19:40: note: candidates are:
9:3: note: B::B(A)
6:8: note: constexpr B::B(const B&)
6:8: note: constexpr B::B(B&&)
```

Changing the expression to `static_cast<A>(static_cast<B>(*this))` doesn't change a thing. Removing that line altogether results in an error message in `main`, as no implicit conversion sequence may use more than one user-defined conversion. In my toy example, I could perform the conversion from `C` to `A` direcly, but in my real life application, doing so would cause a lot of duplicate code, so I'd really like a solution which reuses the other conversion operators.

So how can I obtain a set of three freely interconvertible types without duplicating conversion code?

Comment: Since all the types are classes, you shouldn't really need both a conversion constructor and a conversion operator in each. It should help the ambiguity if you simply provide the conversion constructors in all classes.

Comment: @Angew, problem with conversion constructors only is that it's hard to delegate these. In Java a constructor may delegate to another constructor using `this(…)` but I know of no such mechanism for C++. So every constructor would have to do all the work all by himself.

Comment: @MvG: C++11 supports delegating constructors: http://www.nullptr.me/2012/01/17/c11-delegating-constructors/#.URud1lpp6G4

Comment: @JohnZwinck You're right. Unfortunately, you need a [very recent compiler](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport) to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try this way in struct C:

```
operator A() const { return this->operator B(); }
```

Comment: Letting the implicit conversion handle the second step looks like a nice way to shorten things up. As the `this->` is optional as well, conversions can be written pretty shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
operator A() const { return A(B(value)); }
```

or this:

```
operator A() const { return A(operator B()); }
```

Comment: The former would represent code duplication, as it contains the code I used in `C::operator B()`. But the latter works nicely in my toy example.